# iOS: Detect or disable multiple image selection

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

We have a UIWebview with an image attachment control.

[image]

We the user taps the control an iOS action sheet pops up.

[image]

When the user taps 'Browse' or 'Photo Library' the user can select multiple images.

[image]

I then intercept the

`- (void)imagePickerController: didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:` call with my own ImagePickerViewController that has been swizzled in.

So, my question: In `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo`, is it possible to detect that multiple images have been selected? If not, is there a way to force the image selection on the iOS side to only allow one image?

If possible I would like to detect that multiple images have been selected, and then fall back to normal functionality (i.e. I won't swizzle).

I did examine the picker and info that is sent to `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` as arguments, but even though multiple images are selected, the info parameter only has info on one image. It keeps the first selection and discards the second, and the method is not called a second time.

Edit:
I'm not using a 3rd party image picker.

Comment: `UIImagePickerController` can select only 1 image. In Apple doc it said `Tells the delegate that the user picked a still image or movie.` https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimagepickercontrollerdelegate/1619126-imagepickercontroller

Comment: Are you using any third party image picker?. Because UIImagePickerController will allow you to select only one image at a time. If you are using any third party libraries we have to look into their APIs.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The `UIImagePickerController` calls `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` and then calls `didFinishPickingMultipleMediaWithInfo`. It calls didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo first, I then check

```
if info["UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL"] == nil {
    // process the selected single image, we don't want to process multiple images
} else {
    // do nothing
}
```

Then `didFinishPickingMultipleMediaWithInfo` is called, this time with the proper array, if the number of items in the array is greater than one, we use the normal methods and not the swizzled code, but if there is only one image, we process it with the swizzled methods as normal.

So, we could not disable multiple image selection, but using didFinishPickingMultipleMediaWithInfo, we can detect when multiple images are selected and change how the app behaves in return.

Comment: I know this was answered a while ago but I'm trying to solve this problem and I can't see a delagate for `didFinishPickingMultipleMediaWithInfo` or documentation..is this a legitimate method?