# IOS webkit how to limit select one photo only

Tags: ios, camera, wechat

As I am working with a 3rd party website, and my app using webkit to display the website.
On the website there are button to calling the native camera function
How can I limit the user select one photo only when user click on library.

I have using WeChat to try on same website. And WeChat can doing this.

Comment: You can use `UIImagePickerController` and implement it's delegate functions. You can also choose to handle the single image which it picks. In that regard this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51550756/3050006) might help. To open the image picker you can listen callback from your web view.

Comment: It's same with my case , but I am a new on iOS , is there any complete code can be reference? I implemented the UIImagePickerControllerDelegate , and work with  the didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo call back , but seems not working, how can I link up the ImagePickerdelegate with my VC or webkit

Comment: You can follow this [one](https://theswiftdev.com/picking-images-with-uiimagepickercontroller-in-swift-5/) which I've found on Google I think. Once you complete the tutorial you can apply the solution in that answer I mentioned. Which should work.

Comment: Seem the tut is a little bit different with my case, tut tell us to making a UIImagePickerController rather than connecting the delegate calling from webkit